# How to fine tune a trained model and saved model with tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, transfer-learning, efficientnet

I have a big dataset and I want to train efficientnetb0 by this dataset but google colab gets a run timeout so I want to train the fully connected layers of the model and save it then load it again after some hours and fine-tune the base model(efficientnetb0). how can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in following way. Please change it as per your requirement. This is an snapshot of starting point.

```
if not os.path.exists('e10.h5'):
    model = get_model() #this method constructs the model and compiles it 
else:
    model = load_model('tf_keras_cifar10.h5') #load the model from file
    print('lr is ', K.get_session().run(model.optimizer.lr))
    initial_epoch=10
    epochs=13

history = model.fit(x_train, y_train, batch_size=batch_size, epochs=epochs,validation_data=(x_test, y_test), initial_epoch=initial_epoch)
model.save('e.h5')
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. This code train whole the model. I want to fine-tune the efficientnetb0 that I've used as the base model of my own model. In the other words, I want to train some layers of the model.